# iohook: XKB Keyboard support is required to accurately determine keyboard characters

Tags: electron, keystroke, electron-forge

**I'm trying to listen for keyboard events with iohook. I installed it and when I run my code with iohook it gives me this error:**

`load_input_helper [1918]: Using XFree86 keyboard layout.`

`load_input_helper [1920]: XKB support is required to accurately determine keyboard characters!`

I have the XKB extension installed. I'm on Ubuntu Linux. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I have the EXACT same issue. I hope there's a solution soon.